# adding empty string while joining the 2 lists - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have 2 lists

```
mainlist=[['RD-12',12,'a'],['RD-13',45,'c'],['RD-15',50,'e']] and 
sublist=[['RD-12',67],['RD-15',65]]
```

if i join both the list based on 1st element condition by using below code

```
def combinelist(mainlist,sublist):
   dict1 = { e[0]:e[1:] for e in mainlist }
   for e in sublist:
      try:
         dict1[e[0]].extend(e[1:])
      except:
         pass
   result = [ [k] + v for k, v in dict1.items() ]
   return result
```

Its results in like below

```
[['RD-12',12,'a',67],['RD-13',45,'c',],['RD-15',50,'e',65]]
```

as their is no element in for 'RD-13' in sublist, i want to empty string on that.

The final output should be

```
[['RD-12',12,'a',67],['RD-13',45,'c'," "],['RD-15',50,'e',65]]
```

Please help me.

Comment: In your example you have a space in your "empty string" and it is thus not an empty string but a string consisting of a space. You get an empty string with `""`

Comment: @yatu: No, check on first element only. if no second element in sublist, it should add empty string(a space that specifics as 1 element on that sublist) to that

Comment: You need to loop over the mainlist, not sublist.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go through the result list and check where the total number of your elements is 2 instead of 3.

```
for list in lists:
    if len(list) == 2:
        list.append(" ")
```

**UPDATE:**

If there are more items in the sublist, just subtract the lists containing the 'keys' of your lists, and then add the desired string.

```
def combinelist(mainlist,sublist):
   dict1 = { e[0]:e[1:] for e in mainlist }
   list2 = [e[0] for e in sublist]
   for e in sublist:
      try:
         dict1[e[0]].extend(e[1:])
      except:
         pass
   for e in dict1.keys() - list2:
       dict1[e].append(" ")
   result = [[k] + v for k, v in dict1.items()]
   return result
```

Comment: It cant be done in this way, as i gave example list in the question. the items in sublist are more and cant be countable.

Comment: I've added the update for your edit. It adds a couple of lines on to your code, for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved using a while loop to adjust the length of your sublists until it matches the length of the longest sublist by appending the wanted string.

```
for list in result:
    while len(list) < max(len(l) for l in result):
        list.append(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
mainlist=[['RD-12',12],['RD-13',45],['RD-15',50]]
sublist=[['RD-12',67],['RD-15',65]]
empty_val = ''

# Lists to dictionaries
maindict = dict(mainlist)
subdict = dict(sublist)
result = []
# go through all keys
for k in list(set(list(maindict.keys()) + list(subdict.keys()))):
    # pick the value from each key or a default alternative
    result.append([k, maindict.pop(k, empty_val), subdict.pop(k, empty_val)])
# sort by the key
result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

You can set up your empty value to whatever you need.

**UPDATE**

Following the new conditions, it would look like this:

```
mainlist=[['RD-12',12,'a'], ['RD-13',45,'c'], ['RD-15',50,'e']]
sublist=[['RD-12',67], ['RD-15',65]]

maindict = {a:[b, c] for a, b, c in mainlist}
subdict = dict(sublist)
result = []

for k in list(set(list(maindict.keys()) + list(subdict.keys()))):
    result.append([k, ])
    result[-1].extend(maindict.pop(k, ' '))
    result[-1].append(subdict.pop(k, ' '))

sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: mainlist sub elements has more than 2. as i gave example like that. now i have modified the question as well. that why i convert 1 element as key and add the elements.

Comment: ok, this update should work... for any tuple of more than two, one uses the recursive casting and adds it to result as extend. for tuples of two, use direct dict casting and adds to the results with append.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert the sublist to a dict, so items are easily and rapidly accessible.

```
sublist_dict  = dict(sublist)
```

So you can do (it modifies the `mainlist`):

```
for i, e in enumerate(mainlist):
  data: mainlist[i].append(sublist_dict.get(e[0], ""))
#=> [['RD-12', 12, 'a', 67], ['RD-13', 45, 'c', ''], ['RD-15', 50, 'e', 65]]
```

Or a one liner list comprehension (it produces a new list):

```
[ e + [sublist_dict.get(e[0], "")] for e in mainlist ]
```

---

If you want to skip the missing element:

```
for i, e in enumerate(mainlist):
  data = sublist_dict.get(e[0])
  if data: mainlist[i].append(data)

print(mainlist)
#=> [['RD-12', 12, 'a', 67], ['RD-13', 45, 'c'], ['RD-15', 50, 'e', 65]]
```